# AWS EKS static ip solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

i create cluster

```
eksctl create cluster \
  --version 1.21 \
  --region eu-central-1 \
  --node-type t3.medium \
  --nodes 3 \
  --nodes-min 1 \
  --nodes-max 3 \
  --name cluster
```

after that , i install grafana/prometheus

**a3a4b626096bc4cf5836786f7d1b2ae2-1272374646.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com**
when i ping this link , every time ip is different  , how can i static it ? i mean elastic ip.
i try this solution but still not working .
https://blog.tooljet.com/aws-nat-eks/

Answer (score 1):

`...how can i static it ? i mean elastic ip`

You can use the [annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#other-elb-annotations) `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: <AllocationId>` to associate EIP with the provisioned NLB. Note 1 EIP for 1 availability zone.

Comment: is it same when using eks cluster?

Comment: See the updated answer.